# How to prevent to go to the next tab in vue-form-wizard?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on  vue form wizard (https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard) and I would like  to make a manual validation before to skip to the next tab.

the problem is when I return false in `:before-change` it doesn't work and return error.

```
<tab-content
  icon="fa fa-sign-in"
  title="Internal"
  v-if="purchases.purpose=='internal'"
  :before-change="()=>beforeTabSwitch(2)">
  ...

  <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect"
    v-model="purchases.internal.preferredShippingAddress">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="2">AU Forrestfield</option>
    <option value="3">BE Ghlin</option>
  </select>
  ....

  data() {
    return {
      stepIndex:0,
      formError: false,
      purchases: {
        purpose: 'internal',
        internal: {
          preferredShippingAddress: null,
        },
      },
      title: '',
      subtitle: ''
    }
  },
  ...

  beforeTabSwitch: function(s) {
    if (s === 2) {
      if (this.purchases.internal.preferredShippingAddress !== null) {
        return true;
      } else {
        /*
         *
         *
         * Here I want to stay in the same tab while the 
           value`this.purchases.internal.preferredShippingAddress`==null
         *
         *
         */
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Would you mind to reformat your lines of code? Thanks.

Comment: Returning false should be the correct way. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Hi @MostafaAbdellaoui, I'd like to encourage you to mark an anwer as "accepted" if it answered your question. You can see how and why to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard/blob/9b1730538b391854948164879f9c6d4c63363546/README.md#L35) say:

> Resolving with a truthy value, will trigger the navigation to next step. Rejecting with a message, will set an internal message that can be handled and displayed if needed.

And the linked [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CristiJ/bt5dhqtf/298/) demonstrates that you need to return an error message instead of `false` when you don't want to step to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

by using vee-validate you can do @nextStep="validateStep"

and then

```
validateStep() {
 this.$refs.YOUR_OBSERVER_REF.validate().then((success) => {
   if (!success) {
    this.$refs.wizard.previousTab()
   }
 })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.